# Puppeteer, block window.location and return the page content?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the full content of a pages with puppeteer, this works fine with normal pages but if it does a `window.location` redirect I want to block that redirect and just get the original content:

Ex. If https://example.com/thisredirects returns

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Page not found - Please wait while we redirect you home...</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   window.location = "//example.com";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get that html and block the location redirect. If I try to block/abort the location change with `setRequestInterception` response returns null and it doesn't actually fully block the redirect (it works for a redirect status code, but not a page that returns 200 and then redirects with `window.location`):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const pageUrl = "https://example.com/thisredirects";

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  const requests = [];
  page.on('request', async request => {
    let isNavRequest = request.isNavigationRequest() && request.frame() === page.mainFrame();
    if (!isNavRequest) {
      request.continue();
      return;
    }
    requests.push(request);
    if (requests.length == 1) {
      console.log("Load initial page: " + request.url());
      request.continue();
      return;
    }
    console.log("Block redirect to: " + request.url());
    request.abort();
  });

  let response;
  try {
    console.log(`Request: ${pageUrl}`);
    response = await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    const content = await response.text();
    console.log(content);
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})()
```

Is there a way to block the `window.location` and get the original HTML (as above) without completely disabling javascript?

Even if I listen to all responses:

```
  page.on('response', async response => {
    if (response.ok && response.url() === pageUrl) {
      console.log(await response.text());
    }
  });
```

It can't get the original HTML. It throws `Could not load body for this request. This might happen if the request is a preflight request.`.

Comment: what if you disable javascript before navigating to the webpage? `page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GrafiCode unfortunately disabling javascript even for the page context isn't an option because on the pages that don't redirect (I don't know which ones do/don't beforehand) I need javascript enabled

Answer (score 1):

@GrafiCode's hint about `page.setJavascriptEnabled(false)` is a good one: later on, you can turn it back by setting its value to `true`.

To workaround the problem you can follow this:

1. Disabling JavaScript to prevent `window.location` is reassigned immediately
2. Navigate to the (dysfunctional) page
3. Removing the `<script>` tags that try to manipulate the location (`page.$$eval` or `page.evaluate` puppeteer methods can be used to execute `Element.remove()`)
4. Saving the HTML after the cleaned - redirect-free - markup (`page.content`).
5. Enabling JavaScript
6. Setting the saved HTML on the page (`page.setContent`)
7. You won't be able to access `response.text()` the same way as you tried above (as setContent returns differently than goto) but you can use `page.$eval` on the `innerText` of the `<body>`

```js
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
await page.goto(pageUrl)

await page.$$eval('script', scripts =>
  scripts.forEach(src => {
    if (src.innerHTML.includes('window.location')) src.remove()
  })
)

const html = await page.content()
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
await page.setContent(html)

const text = await page.$eval('body', el => el.innerText)
console.log(text)
```

Output (the content of the `<p>`):

```bash
Page not found - Please wait while we redirect you home...
```

Comment: I ended up finding a way to do this without disabling javascript at all (didn't realise which `request.abort` errorcode you send makes the response chain behave differently). In my situation where I want to log the blocked redirect this was better for me. Thanks for your solution though, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realise sending a different error code (`aborted`) to `request.abort` lets you access the previous requests. With that I was able to access the text from the original response:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

const requests = [];
let redirectBlocked = false;

page.on('request', async request => {
    let isNavRequest = request.isNavigationRequest() && request.frame() === page.mainFrame();
    if (!isNavRequest) {
        request.continue();
        return;
    }

    requests.push(request);
    if (requests.length == 1) {
        request.continue();
        return;
    }

    // *snip* more here to detect legitimate redirects...

    redirectBlocked = true;
    request.abort('aborted');

    let originalResponse = await requests[0].response();
    console.log(await originalResponse.text());
});

const response = await page.goto(pageUrl, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

if (!redirectBlocked) console.log(await response.text());
```

Comment: request.isNavigationRequest() && request.frame() === page.mainFrame() is the very first navigation and therefore blocks everything